# Joining nearest neighbor small polygons using R

Tags: polygon, r, attribute-joins, merge

The [figure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vQ3dXaWpiTkx5dDA/edit?usp=sharing) shows a plot of numerous polygons (zoom in) made from a raster file by

```
require(sp)
require(raster)
pol100 <- rasterToPolygons(r, fun=function(x){x==1}, dissolve=FALSE)
```

There polygon has 2059 features

```
> pol100
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
nfeatures   : 2059 
extent      : 254358.6, 268808.1, 2619318, 2642087  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
nvariables  : 1
names       : value 
min values  :   1 
max values  :   1
```

Each of the small polygons can be explored/plotted individually

```
#if want to plot a particular polygon
plot(pol100[[1]][[500]])
#if want to know the area of a particular polygon (say polygon#100)
#(all polygons are in fact of same size)
pol100@polygons[[100]]@area
```

I want to know if there is any automated way to merge the nearest neighbor polygons? Looking at the figure tells that the process will create approximately 15-20 large polygons, for instance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `plot(coordinates(out[[1]][[200]]), type="l")`?

Comment: okay, can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: look, I made some changes in my data as well as question @rcs

Comment: If it doesn't have to be the nearest neighbors, but if you only want to reduce the complexity, I think you can use, `unionSpatialPolygons {maptools}` and the `ID=` argument to base spatial union on... I did something similar in the answer of this question; http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82667/remove-land-area-from-marine-region-polygons

Answer (score 4):

If you want to combine all polygons that neighbor eachother you can use this method. First, use the `poly2nb` function in the `spdep` package to define the neighbors of each polygon, then use the function defined below to create a vector of region assignments, next use `spCbind` from the `maptools` package to bind regions to `pol`, and finally dissolve over `regions` using the `unionSpatialPolygons` function from `maptools`. The basic structure of the created function is `if` at least one of the polygon's neighbors has been assigned to a group `then` assign polygon and neighbors to that group `else` assign polygon and neighbors to new group.

```
library(raster)
library(spdep)
library(maptools)

r <- raster(nrow=18, ncol=36)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
r[r>8] <- NA
pol <- rasterToPolygons(r, fun=function(x){x>6}, dissolve = T)
plot(pol)

nb <- poly2nb(pol)

create_regions <- function(data) {
  group <- rep(NA, length(data))
  group_val <- 0
  while(NA %in% group) {
    index <- min(which(is.na(group)))
    nb <- unlist(data[index])
    nb_value <- group[nb]
    is_na <- is.na(nb_value)
    if(sum(!is_na) != 0){
      prev_group <- nb_value[!is_na][1]
      group[index] <- prev_group
      group[nb[is_na]] <- prev_group
    } else {
      group_val <- group_val + 1
      group[index] <- group_val
      group[nb] <- group_val
    }
  }
  group
}

region <- create_regions(nb)
pol_rgn <- spCbind(pol, region)
pol2 <- unionSpatialPolygons(pol_rgn, region)
plot(pol2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant way, with the help of `sf` and `stars`:

```r
#' rast2poly
#' @param r A raster object
#' @export
rast2poly <- function(r, crs = 4326) {
    sf_poly = suppressWarnings({
        sf::st_as_sf(stars::st_as_stars(r),
            as_points = FALSE, merge = TRUE
        ) %>% sf::st_make_valid() # %>% sf::as_Spatial()
    })
    sf::st_crs(sf_poly) = crs
    sf_poly
}
pol100 <- rast2poly(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to join the nearest neighbors of a raster cells, you would end up with just a single polygon (the extent). I understand the goal to be to combine raster cells that have the same values into single polygons. For that, you can use `terra::as.polygons`.

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
x <- classify(r, 3)
```

Solution

```
p <- as.polygons(x)
```

See

```
plot(p, "elevation")
#or 
plot(x); lines(p)
```