# Removing land area from marine region polygons using R

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, overlay

In my pursuit to merge multiple polygons for the purpose of calculating the surface area of marine species distributions, using shapefiles from [Marineregions](http://www.marineregions.org/), I am now trying to remove potential land areas that are left in some of the shapefiles.

Below is how I tested going about it. A single species distribution can contain areas from very separate regions making parts of the below code very timely inefficient. In the below example I am using the marine ecoregion [Bahamian](http://www.marineregions.org/gazetteer.php?p=details&id=21980) where I aim at removing the *Bahamas Islands*. (*Choose shapefile in the drop-down menue)*

```
require(sp)
require(ggplot2)
require(mapdata)
require(gridExtra)
require(scales)
require(rgeos)    

# For example read shapefile for Bahamian marine ecoregion. In reality I would be using a merged and unionized polygon from several different marine regions (eez, iho, meow).
bahamian_shp <- readOGR("~/test", layer='bahamian')

# Remove and rename attribute fields
if('eco_code' %in% colnames(bahamian_shp@data)==T){
  bahamian_shp@data<-subset(bahamian_shp@data, select=-c(lat, long, placetype))
  colnames(bahamian_shp@data)[colnames(bahamian_shp@data) == 'ecoregion'] <- 'name'
  colnames(bahamian_shp@data)[colnames(bahamian_shp@data) == 'eco_code'] <- 'id'
  bahamian_shp@data['id']<-paste0(bahamian_shp@data$id, paste0(sprintf("%1s", sample(LETTERS,1)),sprintf("%1s", sample(LETTERS,1))))
  bahamian_shp@data <- bahamian_shp@data[,c(2,1,3)]
}

# Get coordinates for the Bahamas Islands
all <- map_data('worldHires')
# Subset to get Bahamas
bahamas <- all[which(grepl("bahamas", all$region, ignore.case = TRUE)),]
# Create a variable with all the island names
bahamas_islands <- unique(bahamas$subregion)

# Assigns island coordinates to variables named accordingly. Whitespace replaced with underscore
for(island in bahamas_islands){
  for(i in island){
    assign(gsub("\\s","_",i), as.matrix(bahamas[bahamas$subregion==island,c(1,2)]))
  }
}

# Use the bahamian SPDF as a template for the bahamas islands
tmp <- lapply(bahamas_islands, function(x){gsub("\\s","_",x)})
for(i in tmp){
  assign(paste(i, 'spdf', sep="_"), bahamian_shp[1,])
}
```

Below I further noticed the inefficiency of this approach as it currently is. In some of the subregions (i.e. islands) there are even more 'subregions', e.g. one of the island named *Andros Island* corresponds to two sets of coordinates (i.e. two sub islands with the same name); thus giving the error `Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring` if we don't change the name of one of the coordinate sets. For this example I have left out this particular Island. I reckon, if the below step is done more efficiently, I could actually use this approach.

```
# Adjust each SPDF according to each subregion/island. Didn't figure out how to do this with a loop. 
Abaco_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Abaco_Island
Abaco_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Abaco Island'
Abaco_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Abaco_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Abaco_Island_spdf, paste('Abaco2144', 1:nrow(Abaco_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Abaco_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Abaco_Island_spdf@polygons))

Acklins_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Acklins_Island
Acklins_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Acklins Island'
Acklins_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Acklins_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Acklins_Island_spdf, paste('Acklins2144', 1:nrow(Acklins_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Acklins_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Acklins_Island_spdf@polygons))

Cat_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Cat_Island
Cat_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Cat Island'
Cat_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Cat_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Cat_Island_spdf, paste('Cat2144', 1:nrow(Cat_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Cat_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Cat_Island_spdf@polygons))

Crooked_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Crooked_Island
Crooked_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Crooked Island'
Crooked_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Crooked_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Crooked_Island_spdf, paste('Crooked2144', 1:nrow(Crooked_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Crooked_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Crooked_Island_spdf@polygons))

Eleuthera_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Eleuthera_Island
Eleuthera_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Eleuthera Island'
Eleuthera_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Eleuthera_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Eleuthera_Island_spdf, paste('Eleuthera2144', 1:nrow(Eleuthera_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Eleuthera_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Eleuthera_Island_spdf@polygons))

Grand_Bahama_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Grand_Bahama_Island
Grand_Bahama_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Grand Bahama Island'
Grand_Bahama_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Grand_Bahama_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Grand_Bahama_Island_spdf, paste('GrandBahama2144', 1:nrow(Grand_Bahama_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Grand_Bahama_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Grand_Bahama_Island_spdf@polygons))

Great_Exuma_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Great_Exuma_Island
Great_Exuma_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Great Exuma Island'
Great_Exuma_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Great_Exuma_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Great_Exuma_Island_spdf, paste('GreatExuma2144', 1:nrow(Great_Exuma_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Great_Exuma_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Great_Exuma_Island_spdf@polygons))

Great_Inagua_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Great_Inagua_Island
Great_Inagua_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Great Inagua Island'
Great_Inagua_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Great_Inagua_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Great_Inagua_Island_spdf, paste('GreatInagua2144', 1:nrow(Great_Inagua_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Great_Inagua_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Great_Inagua_Island_spdf@polygons))

Hog_Cay_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Hog_Cay
Hog_Cay_spdf@data$name <- 'Hog Cay'
Hog_Cay_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Hog_Cay_spdf <- spChFIDs(Hog_Cay_spdf, paste('HogCay2144', 1:nrow(Hog_Cay_spdf), sep=""))
Hog_Cay_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Hog_Cay_spdf@polygons))

Little_Inagua_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Little_Inagua_Island
Little_Inagua_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Little Inagua Island'
Little_Inagua_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Little_Inagua_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Little_Inagua_Island_spdf, paste('LittleInagua2144', 1:nrow(Little_Inagua_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Little_Inagua_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Little_Inagua_Island_spdf@polygons))

Long_Cay_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Long_Cay
Long_Cay_spdf@data$name <- 'Long Cay'
Long_Cay_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Long_Cay_spdf <- spChFIDs(Long_Cay_spdf, paste('LongCay2144', 1:nrow(Long_Cay_spdf), sep=""))
Long_Cay_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Long_Cay_spdf@polygons))

Long_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Long_Island
Long_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Long Island'
Long_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Long_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Long_Island_spdf, paste('Long2144', 1:nrow(Long_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Long_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Long_Island_spdf@polygons))

Mayaguana_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Mayaguana_Island
Mayaguana_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'Mayaguana Island'
Mayaguana_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Mayaguana_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(Mayaguana_Island_spdf, paste('Mayaguana2144', 1:nrow(Long_Island_spdf), sep=""))
Mayaguana_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Mayaguana_Island_spdf@polygons))

New_Providence_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- New_Providence_Island
New_Providence_Island_spdf@data$name <- 'New Providence Island'
New_Providence_Island_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
New_Providence_Island_spdf <- spChFIDs(New_Providence_Island_spdf, paste('NewProvidence2144', 1:nrow(New_Providence_Island_spdf), sep=""))
New_Providence_Island_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(New_Providence_Island_spdf@polygons))

Rum_Cay_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Rum_Cay
Rum_Cay_spdf@data$name <- 'Rum Cay Island'
Rum_Cay_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Rum_Cay_spdf <- spChFIDs(Rum_Cay_spdf, paste('RumCay2144', 1:nrow(Rum_Cay_spdf), sep=""))
Rum_Cay_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Rum_Cay_spdf@polygons))

Samana_Cay_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- Samana_Cay
Samana_Cay_spdf@data$name <- 'Samana Cay Island'
Samana_Cay_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
Samana_Cay_spdf <- spChFIDs(Samana_Cay_spdf, paste('SamanaCay2144', 1:nrow(Samana_Cay_spdf), sep=""))
Samana_Cay_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(Samana_Cay_spdf@polygons))

San_Salvador_spdf@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords <- San_Salvador
San_Salvador_spdf@data$name <- 'San Salvador'
San_Salvador_spdf@data$mrgid <- 2144
San_Salvador_spdf <- spChFIDs(San_Salvador_spdf, paste('SanSalvador2144', 1:nrow(San_Salvador_spdf), sep=""))
San_Salvador_spdf@polygons[[1]]@area <- gArea(SpatialPolygons(San_Salvador_spdf@polygons))

# Make a list of the island SPDFs
bahamas_shp_list <- as.list(c(Abaco_Island_spdf,Acklins_Island_spdf,Cat_Island_spdf,Crooked_Island_spdf,Eleuthera_Island_spdf,Grand_Bahama_Island_spdf,Great_Exuma_Island_spdf,Great_Inagua_Island_spdf,Hog_Cay_spdf,Little_Inagua_Island_spdf,Long_Cay_spdf, Long_Island_spdf, Mayaguana_Island_spdf,New_Providence_Island_spdf,Rum_Cay_spdf,Samana_Cay_spdf,San_Salvador_spdf))

# Polygons seem to be plotted in alphabetical, so in order so make sure the bahamian ecoregion is plotted last we rename it
bahamian@data$name <- 'zBahamian'

# Join/merge all the island SPDFs into one
bahamas_joined_spdf <- do.call("rbind", bahamas_shp_list)

# Insert the bahamian SPDF into the one for the bahamas islands
new_shp <- spRbind(bahamian_shp, bahamas_joined_spdf)
# ggplot requires a data frame, so use the fortify() function
mydf <- fortify(new_shp, region = "name")


# Make a distinction between the underlying island shapes and the overlying ecoregion polygon so that we can manually set the colours
mydf$filltype <- ifelse(mydf$id == 'zBahamian', "colour1", "colour2")

# Make the plot
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(colour = "black", size = 1, aes(fill = mydf$filltype)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Test", values = c(alpha("cyan", 0.4), "white"), labels = c("ecoregion", "bahamas islands"))
```

[image]

With these polygon layers we can remove the island area from the ecoregion by using the `gDifference()` function from the `rgeos package`.

I seek any alternative, more efficient ways of doing this, which im sure there are, since I am a beginner in R and spatial data analysis in general. I cannot imagine doing this for species having much larger, geographically disperse distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a way.

I use [this](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip) World map shapefile

```
# Read in new shapefile
world <- readOGR("~/test", layer="TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3")
# Order after $REGION in the 8th column
world_attri <- world@data[ order(-world@data[,8], world@data[,1]), ]
# Extract first line of each unique $REGION
world_attri <- world_attri[!duplicated(world_attri$REGION),]
# Subset the data to make the number of field equal to the Bahamian_shp
world_attri_subset <- subset(world_attri, select=c("NAME", "ISO3", "REGION"))
# Rename those fields to the same as the Bahamian_shp
colnames(world_attri_subset) <- c('name', 'id', 'mrgid')
# Reduce it by making a union based on $REGION
world_merged <- unionSpatialPolygons(world, world$REGION)
# Set the rownames to be equal to the mrgid field
rownames(world_attri_subset) <- world_attri_subset$mrgid
# Make a new SPDF
world_spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Sr=world_merged, data=world_attri_subset)

#### Following the above procedure ####

# Polygons seem to be plotted in alphabetical, so in order so make sure the bahamian ecoregion is plotted last we rename it
bahamian@data$name <- 'zBahamian'

# Insert the bahamian SPDF into the one for the world_spdf
new_spdf <- spRbind(bahamian_shp, world_spdf)
# ggplot requires a data frame, so use the fortify() function
mydf <- fortify(new_spdf, region = "name")

# Make a distinction between the underlying land shapes and the overlying ecoregion  polygon so that we can manually set the colours
mydf$filltype <- ifelse(mydf$id == 'zBahamian', "colour1", "colour2")

# Make the plot
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(colour = "black", size = 1, aes(fill = mydf$filltype)) +
  + coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_manual("Test", values = c(alpha("cyan", 0.4), "white"), labels = c("Bahamian", "World"))

### Calculate the corrected area (i.e. without land area) ###

diff <- gDifference(bahamian_shp, world_spdf, byid=FALSE, id=NULL)
gArea(SpatialPolygons(diff@polygons))
# 83.69948    ## Seems legit if one compares with the below area of the whole Bahamian

gArea(SpatialPolygons(bahamian_shp@polygons))
# 84.87498

(Area in square degrees since it's not projected in UTM)
```

[image]
[image]

This approach is probably more computationally demanding compared to the previous, but at least gaining efficiency in terms of reduced manual labour.